# @UniqueConstraint does not affect DELETE statement on @CollectionTable Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

We have an Entity with embedded collection.

1) Initial configuration

```
@Entity @Table
public class A implements Serializable { 
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A"))
    private Set<B> embedded = new HashSet<B>();
}

@Embeddable
public class B implements Serializable {
    private String unique;
    private String nullable;
}
```

When removing an object with this configuration Hibernate generates a Query similar to

```
DELETE FROM A_B WHERE A = ? AND unique = ? AND nullable = ?
```

This does not work, when nullable field is actually NULL, due to SQL NULL equals.

2) Adding @UniqueConstraint

I tried to mitigate this using @UniqueConstraint, which suppose to handle this case

```
@Entity @Table
public class A implements Serializable { 
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A"), uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"unique"}))
    private Set<B> embedded = new HashSet<B>();
}
```

This did not change a Query at all.

Finally I solved it by using propriatery Hibernate @SQLDelete annotation

3) Adding @SQLDelete

```
@Entity @Table
public class A implements Serializable { 
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A"), uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"unique"}))
@SQLDelete(sql = "delete from A_B where A=? and unique=? and (1 = 1 OR nullable = ?)")

    private Set<B> embedded = new HashSet<B>();
}
```

I have a strict requirements to use only JPA 2.0 annotations, so I might need to remove my solution - 3.

How can I make a 2 configuration working, using standard JPA 2.0 ?
Do I need some additional annotations except @UniqueConstraint in @CollectionTable?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an Embeddable type, can't/shouldn't you use @AttributeOverrides on the Set and then set the Column in the embeddable type to Nullable?

```
  @AttributeOverrides({
  @AttributeOverride(name="UNIQUE_COLUMN", column=@Column(name="UNIQUE"))

  @Column(name = "UNIQUE", nullable = true)
```